# How to deactivate non-integral versions of my `Pow(T)` using SFINAE?

Tags: c++, sfinae

I am asked to use SFiNAE to reject non-integral versions of my `Pow(T)` template function. So if the type deduced is an integral then return `argument * argument` otherwise do nothing and just inform that the version has been rejected by SFINAE.

Here is my try:

```
template<typename T>
auto Pow(T x)->std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>
{
    return x * x;
}

void Pow(...)
{
    std::cout << "rejected by SFiNAE" << std::endl;
}


int main() 
{
    auto ret = Pow(5); // error here:  'ret': variable cannot have the type 'void'
    cout << typeid(Pow(5)).name() << endl; // void
}
```

- Please help. I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: You should use `static_assert`. If `T` is integral then code can be compiled, otherwise it must be discarded - at compile-time. What behaviour do you want to get for `double d = Pow(5.5)` (it cannot work because of void as return type), you want printed error on console `rejected by SFINAE` ? Or stop compiling, with error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide the second parameter to `std::enable_if`:

```
template<typename T>
auto Pow(T x)->std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, decltype(x * x)>
{
    return x * x;
}
```